# Are the packages installed by the installer marked as manual?

Tags: apt

I am using the mini.iso installer. I am assuming that the installer installs the basic utils/packages/etc like:

```
apt install pkg_1 pkg_2 pkg_3 .... pkg_n
```

Are these marked as manual ? If I run `apt-mark showmanual` RIGHT AFTER the install, will I only and exactly see:

```
pkg_1 
pkg_2
pkg_3
.
.
.
pkg_n
```

?

Assuming pkg_x has some dependencies which are not other pkg's , then they will be excluded from the list above, correct ?

Comment: Do not assume that the netboot (mini) .iso installs anything beyond a single admin user, a basic network connection, and apt. It's not intended for new or unskilled users. It does not install many basic utilities and services. Misuse will result in a poor experience. It offers no protection from accidental autoremoval of your entire desktop. It is not compatible with UEFI systems. It is not recommended for beginners. Ubuntu has a great Desktop Installer for new users that is safe, offers a much better user experience, and installs a fully-featured, tested set of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since those dependencies were **auto**matically determined instead of **manual**ly specified, they will show up on the showauto list instead of the showmanual list.

Take a look at `man apt-mark`, which clearly explains how apt-marking works.